# How to capture video from UDP using openvino's opencv

Tags: python, opencv, windows-10, python-3.7, openvino

### Setup

```
OpenVINO 2021.2 
Python 3.7
Windows 10
```

### Problem

I can do face detection from video file (webm) and laptop camera (0) but not from a UDP stream.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://0.0.0.0:12345')
```

Error Message:

```
MFX: Unsupported extension: udp://0.0.0.0:12345
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? e.g. manual compilation steps of opencv or other methods.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line :

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://0.0.0.0:12345')
```

You need to add a **@** symbol here. It means listen to address.

It should look like :

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://@0.0.0.0:12345') #Notice the @
```

Comment: @user3705497 how configured your sender?

Comment: @eri h264 udp stream from drone tello. i know it's port 11111. it's working fine on regular opencv-python (via pip) but not when using openvino's opencv